# Error de codigo: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c++, array, struct

Por que estoy obteniendo esto:

```
lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

En esta linea de código:

```
original[0] = 100;
```

El código que tengo es este:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

struct barco
{
    int personas[10];
    int operator[](int c)
    {
        return personas[c];
    }
};


int tamanio = 10;
queue < list <barco> > cola;
list <barco> visitados;
int perm[12][2];

barco original;
barco obj;

int arre[4];

void arregloInicio() {
    original[0] = 100;
    original[1] = 52;
    original[2] = 46;
    original[3] = 49;
    original[4] = 0;
    original[5] = 0;
    original[6] = 0;
    original[7] = 0;
    original[8] = 0;
    original[9] = 0;        
}
```

Comment: @Trauma Ops! Borrado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fijémonos en tu clase:

```
struct barco {
  int operator[]( int c ) {
    return personas[c];
  }
};
```

Tu `operator[]( )` devuelve **por copia**; podríamos decir que devuelve **un valor temporal** (un *rvalue*); y, casualmente, los tipos `int` no admiten/tienen/implementan algo parecido a `operator=( int ) &&`

Para hacer lo que pretendes, basta con devolver **por referencia**:

```
int &operator[]( int c ) {
  return personas[c];
}
```